# Print unreferenced orphans from single table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table (oracle database if it's important) that looks like this:

```
NAME        VALUE
parent.1    aa1234
parent.2    bb1234
child.3H    hh1234
child.2B    bb1234
child.6P    oo6666
parent.3    hh1234
child.1A    aa1234
child.5K    ee9999
child.2C    bb1234
child.1A    aa1234
child.3G    hh1234
```

The table contains parents and children in pretty random order. They referencing each other by the `VALUE` column. A parent has same string value as it's child. Parents usually have one or more children, so parent and it's children will have exact same value.

This is an example, but it's valid to distinguish parent from child by substring `like '%parent%'` or `like '%child%'`. Both `NAME` and `VALUE` columns are `NVARCHARS2(255)`.

I'm trying to find orphans - children that don't have a parent by the value (in the example `child.6p` and `child.5K`). Is it possible in one query or script?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `not exists` as follows:

```
SELECT T.NAME, T.VALUE
  FROM YOUR_TABLE T
 WHERE T.NAME LIKE '%child%'
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                     FROM YOUR_TABLE T1
                    WHERE T1.NAME LIKE '%parent%'
                      AND T.VALUE = T1.VALUE);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from tab C
where NAME  LIKE ('child%')
AND NOT EXISTS 
( SELECT 1 FROM TAB P WHERE 
 P.NAME LIKE ('parent%') 
 AND C.VAL = P.VAL
 )
```

[SQL Fiddel Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a511be/2)